# How to call model method from events?

Tags: backbone.js

I have method in model:

```
decrease: function(){
    this.save({
        count: this.get('count') - 1
    });
}
```

Next, i call method in view for event:

```
'click [data-skills="minus"]': 'decrease'
```

And from this method, i call method from model: (#3)

```
decrease: function(){
    this.model.decrease();
}
```

Is there some way to call model's method directly from events? Without step #3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
events: {
    'click [data-skills="minus"]': function(){
       this.model.decrease();
     }
}
```